# Why is this number rounded down?

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I'm puzzled by the behavior of Java's `NumberFormat`.

Consider the following method that turns a double value into its percent representation and rounds the resulting percentage to three decimal places:

```
public static String doubleToPercent(final double val) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    // Default rounding mode is HALF_EVEN
    nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
    return nf.format(val);
}
```

The rounding mode is `HALF_UP`.

The result in `worksAsExpected` does not surprise me; the test passes:

```
@Test
public void worksAsExpected() {
    double input = 1.234585;
    String expected = "123.459%";
    String output = doubleToPercent(input);
    assertEquals(expected, output);
}
```

But what about this:

```
@Test
public void surprise() {
    double input = 1.234535;
    String expected = "123.454%";
    String output = doubleToPercent(input);
    assertEquals(expected, output);
}
```

Why does this test fail? Why is `1.234535` rounded down while `1.234585` is rounded up?

On the other hand if the last digit is a `6`, the number is rounded up.

```
@Test
public void noSurprise() {
    double input = 1.234536;
    String expected = "123.454%";
    String output = doubleToPercent(input);
    assertEquals(expected, output);
}
```

Has this something to do with the limits of `double`'s precision? I'd guess that a number such as `1.234535` is well within `double`'s capabilities.

I'm on Java 1.7.0_51 running Windows 7 x86.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.234535 = 1.2345349999999999379696191681432537734508514404296875 as a double, so to 6 digits it rounds down to 1.23453.

You can use my decimal/binary converter [exploringbinary.com/binary-converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/) to see what happens.

Note: Unlike normal binary numbers, the exact decimal representation of a binary fraction always has the same number of digits:

```
0.001 =
0.125, 

0.1101101 =
0.8515625, 

0.00001110101011 =
0.05731201171875, 

1.0011110000001010011111000101101011000100011100011011 =
1.2345349999999999379696191681432537734508514404296875

etc.
```

If you need more control over the decimal places and rounding, you'll have to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Note that it would be good to calculate the rounding errors for each operation that you do on a number. [See this question for details](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors).

Comment: Have you used a tool to get that number?

Comment: @ Matthias Braun Yes. I used my decimal/binary converter (http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/ ), For 1.234535 it returns 1.00111100000010100111110001011010110001000111000110110100011110..., which to 53 bits rounds to 1.0011110000001010011111000101101011000100011100011011. I then put that in the binary to decimal converter to get 1.2345349999999999379696191681432537734508514404296875. (There are other ways -- probably easier -- to do this though.)

Comment: @Aaron Digulla That's some pretty heavy editing. Is it normal to delete comments, move comments into answers, and combine answers?

Comment: No but my answer was only partially correct, you obviously know more about this than me and there was so much useful information floating around in the comments that I felt I should fix that. This seemed to be the best fix. Feel free to improve my edits :-)

Comment: My main objection is over the last paragraph (about BigDecimal) -- I did not write it. Can you attribute that to whoever did? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are stored using Double-precision floating-point format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

I am not surprised that you are encountering problems with the precision, unfortunately `double` in Java is not a very reliable way to perform accurate computations.
It is also one of the reasons because for mathematical modules other tools like Matlab are preferred.

Anyway, in your example you may solve your problem (hopefully) increasing the number on the digits in `nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(<something bigger than 3>);`

Or you can switch to `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat` depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks. `DecimalFormat` produces incorrect results as well. But I agree that `BigDecimal` is the way to go.

Comment: I'm confused by the comment about Matlab. Matlab and Java both use IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point to represent double.